What does this hill look like -- a neolithic tell, a tumulus, a vineyard terrace?
Southern Romania is full of tells (popularly called "măguri" in Romanian) dated to the neolithic culture of Gumelnița. Recently I have seen one such hill close to the villages of Mavrodin and Călinești (Teleorman county), which seems scarcely documented - and, maybe luckily, poorly known even by the locals, something which has contributed to its preservation, unlike what happened to many others in the region (closer to human habitation and agricultural activity). This one is more isolated between two forest areas. It is called Măgura Zamfirei (Zamfira's Hill).  If you look it up the internet a business that uses that name and was opened in proximity will pop up everywhere in web and image searches, but Google maps shows pictures of it: HERE.



I wasn't able to find much information, just lists where the spot is mentioned in some official documents like
LISTA MONUMENTELOR ISTORICE 2015 - Județul Teleorman (List of Historical Monuments of Teleorman county 2015)

-- and in papers like here and here mentioning the location close to those villages, the fact that it has a diameter of approximately 140 meters and a height of about 6 meters, and that Neolithic flint tools and ceramic fragments have been found on it.
It seems to me that scientific sources are all based on the contribution of one person, Ion Spiru (1914-1995) a local priest, a passionate but not fully professional archeologist and historian, in the years 1950s. His articles published along the years have been re-published in one volume in 2014.
The most detailed and direct info I found is this (p.79):
"Neolithic. 'Măgura Zamfirei,' 140 meters in diameter and 6 meters in height, north of Mavrodin and south of the village of Călineşti, in the forest. I found a few fragmented ceramics and some flint tools. I couldn't determine which culture it belongs to. It could just as well be another tumulus."
Doesn't it look excessively well-preserved? Or is it normal for a Neolithic tell to be so well-preserved, even exposed in the middle of a flat field? (Or the fact that in the past it might have been covered by forrest contributed to the preservation?) Do the large and clearly defined terraces fit the structure of a neolithic development of houses built, burnt and rebuilt upon each other? Doesn't it look more like a vineyard? Or is it a tumulus?

Some notes after reading the comments:

This is by no means a rare object, it is just one of the best preserved, if not the best I have ever seen. Searching the Wikipedia list there are 20 "tell-type settlements" recorded  just for the Teleorman county. Most of them have descriptions that mention neolithic remains.
It is by no means a church. Churches in the region are not set upon terraces but are on flat ground in the middle of villages.
I am not a specialist and haven't read enough on this topic, but I think I've read at some point that some tells of this type were set on the rivers and small islands of such waters. The very small water close by has surely been much bigger in the past (and considerably bigger until 50 years ago or less) and the whole region much more swampy.
I don't know what the soil is made of, but it is suposed to be part of the culture and structures that are described for example in this video. There were groups of houses that were periodically (maybe ritually) burnt and immediately new ones were rebuilt on top, which led to this mounds. The interior should look like so (images from the video):




I wasn't able to find other confirmed neolithic tell featuring such clear-cut terraces. If it is a tell at all, it could have been re-used. But to what purpose it is very hard to imagine, because the site is rather isolated in a forested area and doesn't fit a vineyard location, unless sometime in the past a village was located closer to it (for the moment I have no proof of that though.) It also seems too small for a vineyard, which in the region are frequent and cover low but extended natural hills. As I said, it doesn't fit a church either.


What is it made of?  If it's just piled-up soil, it's pretty unlikely to have survived intact for many years in a wet climate. (I doubt that being formerly covered by forest would have aided in preservation of heaped up soil.)

A 1901 geographical guide mentions this feature, the translation I get says 'cemetery' so I guess that would lean towards the tumulus conclusion.

@justCal - It would be nice to have a more recent opinion on that subject. Science has advanced rather a lot since then. In 1901 most people still didn't believe in Germ Theory.

True, but geographical gazattes often relied on collections of local knowledge. Sometimes older knowledge is required to get beyond modern politicizing as well.

I've just looked at older aerial views of the feature in Google Earth. Especially the older pictures from around 2010-15 show incredibly detailed structures: sharp corners, narrow interruptions (2 m), a curious cross-like feature with a central rectangular form (12 * 25 m) on top. I do not believe for one minute that things like that could have survived a couple of milennia intact. So either there have been active excavation works in recent decades, or these structures are new.

Is anyone else reminded of the ground plan of a church looking at the central structure at the top? Especially as it has a perfect east-west alignment and the rounded side points east, like an apsis would?

Screenshot of the 2010 aerial view.

@MarkOlson - See my added comments, youtube link and images.

@T.E.D. - There is new literature, only not exactly on this tell, but on the larger phenomenon. I will look into it and post here.

@justCal - I think the neolithic period in this region suffers less (than other periods) from politicization and more from neglect (sometimes because of the sheer abundance of remains).

@T.E.D. - Here is a recent article in English on a close by tell. These structures are popularly called "măguri" in Romanian.

@ccprog - If such things cannot survive for millenia how come we talk about surviving tells and tumuli in Eastern Europe, which are bound to be at least 2-3 millennia old? For the neolithic ones they can be twice that age. If this is not one of them there are others anyway, but most look like hills.Oddly, pictures of them are easier to find on google maps than on archeological internet sites.

@cipricus I am not talking about the hill itself, but about the terrace structures at the surface. If the hill consists of mainly silt, sand and gravel, like the tell described in the article you linked, such forms would need regular human intervention to preserve their form.

@ccprog - Point taken. In fact, that's what made me post this. But using Google Earth to look at other tells in that list I have found others with terraces, for example 44.165°N 24.97°E. Maybe old tells have been at some point re-used as terraced vineyards or something.

In that example, I think you are mistaking the rectangular field to the south with the round hill to the north of the mark. There are nice Street View pictures available from the site, made this summer. You can see the field to the south doubles as a paddock and a football field. The linear structures in the aerial view are probably traces of cutting the gras down for a game. The hill has no discernable terraces.

@ccprog - Silly of me, yes! I wasn't able to find in fact other confirmed neolithic tell featuring such clear-cut terraces. If it is a tell at all, the Calinesti one must have been re-used. But to what purpose, it is hard to imagine.

Is the an objective question or an opinion based question? is it possible to provide an Authoritative answer?

@MCW - I've stated the official description of the object (ascertained in official documents by the Romanian authorities, the list of historical monuments being published in "Monitorul Oficial"= the "Official Gazette" in English - the publication where Romanian laws, decrees, and other official government acts are published and made public), which is very terse. I have also stated my opinion and the doubts I have. -  But my knowledge is limited and what I ask is clear: a tell being a common archeological object, does this look like one or not.
